Did "seedy" bars in the 19th-century and early 20th-century really stage mock-fights?
A trope that I have encountered several times in popular culture is where rich/fancy clients
visit a "seedy" bar frequented by among others prostitutes, sailors and criminals. Suddenly
a fight breaks out between two "lowerclass" clients. However afterwards this fight turns out to be staged and is organised only to entertain the uppeclass clientele, which are kept unaware from the fact that the fight is staged.
Is there documentation that this (regulary) did happen?
As requested, an example below from the comic book January Jones 2, "De schedel van sultan Mwawa"  



Specific examples might help.

I'm not sure that in 40+ years of reading a wide range of literature that I've ever seen that...

Me either, and I basically lived in front of a TV watching HBO (movie channel) in the 1980's.

Good update! Out of curiosity, was this always in German sources when you saw it?

@T.E.D. That's Dutch, and it takes place in Paris.

Point is, I suspect this might have been something done in a single cultural area in Europe, if it happened at all. That explains the question when I've never heard of such a thing. All I could find in English-language sources for staged fights was at old-west-style tourist attractions, and real fights. I'd suspect a bar owner in the US would be too worried about a staged fight snowballing into a real brawl and causing real damage, which they perhaps might even be found legally liable for.

We do have places that have contained fighting shows, like boxing or luchador matches, or even Jousting, but I'm pretty sure that's not what's being asked about.

I wonder if this is an European stereotype of the USA?  Kind of like their assumption that we all carry revolvers on each hip.   What era are the sources? What era do they putatively depict?
